# Hide Default Report Folder

Tags: reporting

There is an option to set report folder to be open to all internal users. I am trying to remove all internal users so that regular users won't see the default folder when they go to the report and dashboard page.
How can I get the configuration for setting permission -meta.xml so that I can apply this setting to another environment?